# How do i establish a connection from ServiceNow to my SQL database?

Tags: sql, json, database-connection, servicenow

How do i establish a connection from ServiceNow to my SQL database? 
The data being fetched is in JSON format and needs to entered in a table with specified columns. 
The APIs created will need to fetch the latest data into the SQL database

Comment: Please provide some more clarity and detail.  It sounds like you want to create an API that reaches over to ServiceNow and pulls certain data back, which will be in JSON format.  And then that data needs to be stuffed into your SQL Server.  Is that correct?

Comment: See the answer from Ashvini: https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=12458f30dbded340c310fb651f961949

Comment: @DBro ..I already have an API built within servicenow with the endpoint available. I want to pull data from 3 particular tables at regular intervals. The data fetched will be in JSON format and i need to input this data into my tables in SQL. I want to know how do i use the fetched data in JSON format and update it in SQL at regular intervals

Comment: Which technology will you be using to regularly retrieve the JSON, and forward on to your SQL database?  For example, will you be using Python, a C# console app, a script of some sort, etc?

Comment: Getting data from an SQL database and storing it in ServiceNow can be done with a data source and an SQL database available on a midserver. Putting data in an SQL database from ServiceNow can be done if there's a web service API on the database to support that operation.